# Bootstrap CSS Active Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the Bootstrap website the subnav matches up with the sections and changes background color as you or scroll to the section. I wanted to create my own menu without all the background colors and everything, however, I changed my CSS to be similar but when I scroll down or click on the menu item the active class does not switch. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  list-style:none;
}
.menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.menu > li > a {
  color: #555;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 16px 11px;
  display: block;
}
.menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #F95700;
}
.menu a[aria-current="page"],
.menu a[aria-current="page"]:hover {
  color:#F95700;
}
```

I checked the files; jQuery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css are all linked properly. Do I have to add some additional jQuery in or am I missing some CSS to get the active to switch like the subnav menu on their site?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to switch the class, you need to perform some JavaScript.

In jQuery:

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

In JavaScript:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var anchors = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function() { clickHandler(anchors[i]) }, false);
}

function clickHandler(anchor) {
  var hasClass = anchor.getAttribute('class');
  if (hasClass !== 'active') {
    anchor.setAttribute('class', 'active');
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried adding in the jquery under the jquery 1.7.1 and bootstrap.js before the closing body tag and it didn't work. I don't know jquery very well, figured I just missed calling something from the bootstrap css or js file. Oh well, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You need to make sure that the DOM is ready in order for you to be able to grab the selectors.

In jQuery, add `$(document).ready(function() { // add code here } );`

Comment: I modified the jQuery. It turns out `.not()` does NOT return a boolean of `true` or `false`. Now I'm checking if it does not have that class.

Comment: I think I will try to get it working using the scrollspy, but even that is a pain in the ass. Wish the documentation was better.

Comment: Part of the problem was I was using a cufon font, didn't realize it caused problems with colors. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 50):

This is what I ended up with since you have to clear the others as well.

```
$('.navbar li').click(function(e) {
    $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: would you please post the whole context? which is navbar, which is li? and where is this block of javascript placed? sorry but javascripts are really difficult to understand for me

Comment: If the default navbar sets `Home` to `active`, how would you go about maintaining the new `li` as active when the link is clicked and the new page is being loaded,i.e without `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @David My issue is this. I see the class `active` being applied to the `li`s after clicked but the link does not change. But, if I remove `e.preventDefault();` when I click it apply the `active` to the `li` but in a second the `active` class move to the default, in this case, the `<li class="active">Home</li>. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: ¡Man!, your are awesome :D

Answer (score 20):

this is my code for handling twitter bootstrap navigation list:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');                
        });            
    });
```

Comment: wow this is worked for me when tried with code igniter. u r so awesome :)

Comment: e.preventDefault() will prevent the link to open.

Answer (score 17):

## I use 2 1-liners, depending on how my nav is structured

Just make sure that none of your links have active class to start.

### actual links

If your nav links are on separate HTML files (like a layout template in express.js that has a menu), you can do this:

```
$('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + document.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

### hash links

If they are hashes, do this:

```
$('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').click(function(){  $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); });
```

If you don't want to scroll on hash-click, return false:

```
 $('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').click(function(){  $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false; });
```

Comment: +1 for solid solutions that work for both styles of navigation!

Comment: what happens if the href attribute is pointing to the root href="/" or if more parameters were added to the url along the way ?? it will fail big time ! NEVER trust the user !!!

Comment: You're not trusting the user. The client-side javascript is parsing links that you put in the HTML. If you want it to work, don't put `/` in front of links or modify my snippets to include `/`.

Comment: Mine is an example, I generally tailor it to the style of links I am using (which I always have control of.) For your example of params being needed, try `$('ul.nav > li > a[href^="' + document.location.pathname + '"]')` as the selector.

Comment: @konsumer : u r awesome! :)

Answer (score 8):

Looking at some of the other answers, if you want the webpage to scroll down to that section when a side menu is clicked then you don't want to `preventDefault`.

Additionally, you only need to remove the current active class and add a new one not search through all li's. You also want the code to not do anything when the list item you've selected is already active—not needlessly add and remove the same active class. Lastly you should put your event listener on the a element not the li as it has an easier time of triggering a click event on iPhones and tablets, etc. Could also use `.delegate` so you don't have to wait for a DOM ready event. So in the end I'd do something like this (I assume you've preloaded jQuery):

```
$('body').delegate('.menu li a', 'click', function(){
    var $thisLi = $(this).parents('li:first');
    var $ul = $thisLi.parents('ul:first');
    if (!$thisLi.hasClass('active')){
        $ul.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $thisLi.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this code :

```
 <script>
      var curentFile = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
      if (curentFile == "") curentFile = "Default.aspx";
      $('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + curentFile + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
 </script>
```

It's work like a charm .

Answer (score 3):

I did something different to solve this (fyi, i'm a complete html/css/js amateur).

Each of my navbar buttons goes to a new page.  so, in each page's html, i put something like this at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
       $("#aboutButton").removeClass("active");
    });

    $(document).ready( function(){
       $("#dashboardButton").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

That got it working right away for me.

P.S. I tried the accepted answer but had no luck as it would also need to remove the 'active' class from the currently active button to truly 'switch' over.  I'm sure it's possible, but again, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Tested and it works fine.

```
    $('.navbar li').click(function(e) {
        $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }

    });

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            . . . 
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

anyone having problems with this using jsp, watch your packages.

document.location.pathname gave me: /packagename/index.jsp

but my href in my navbar called just index.jsp

So to edit konsumer's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var string = document.location.pathname.replace('/Package Name/','');
   $('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + string + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
} );
```

Comment: totes. mine is just for top-level links, pulled code from running project. Might be better to do 

$('ul.nav > li > a[href="' + document.location + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of the top answers above, it works for ".active" class, but the links not working well, it still stays on the current page. Then I tried this:

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

I found it here: [Twitter Bootstrap add active class to li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li/12950620#12950620)

Comment: Worked fine with links:) Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="~/Cases/Index"><i class="fa fa-font fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Audit Case</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Cases/Auditplan"><i class="fa fa-font fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Audit Plan</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Cases/Auditreport"><i class="fa fa-font fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Audit Report</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Cases/Company"><i class="fa fa-font fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Company Details</span></a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('.main-menu li > a[href="' + document.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your JavaScript:

```
$(".menu li").click(function(e) {
    $(".menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is getting pretty old and clustered with answers, but I took the top answer and made it better. The top answer only works if there's one on the page. This scopes it to removing active from `sibling` elements and adding it to the one you clicked.

I also added the class `nav-toggle` so that it doesn't interfere with things that already have bootstrap js attached.

```
$('.nav.nav-toggle li').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings().removeClass('active');
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
      $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```