# Twitter Bootstrap add active class to li

Tags: jquery, menu, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter bootstrap, and I need to initiate active class to the li portion of the main nav. Automagically.
We use php not ruby.

Sample nav :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/forums">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/faqs.php">FAQ's</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item.php">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="/create.php">Create</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap code is as follows:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

So just need to figure out how to append the class active to the current page. Have looked thru nearly every answer on Stack, with no real joy.

I had played with this:

```
/*menu handler*/
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;  
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $('.nav li a').each(function(){  
        var currentPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        if (activePage == currentPage) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        } 
    });
})
```

But no joy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Twitter-Bootstrap navigation to show active link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link)

Comment: That question is Ruby though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We managed to fix in the end:

```
/*menu handler*/
$(function(){
  function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.substr(-1) == '/') {
      return str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
  }

  var url = window.location.pathname;  
  var activePage = stripTrailingSlash(url);

  $('.nav li a').each(function(){  
    var currentPage = stripTrailingSlash($(this).attr('href'));

    if (activePage == currentPage) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    } 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 130):

**For Bootstrap 3:**

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

## Update

**For Bootstrap 4:**

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.navbar-nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.navbar-nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Works perfectly with my MVC

Comment: Old question but i just jump here, what if i have a dropdown? and children href don't match parent but i wanna set parent as active

Comment: @DannyG - wouldn't you just add something like this to the end of code? ".parent().parent().addClass('active');"

Comment: Works well, thanks. But what's the technicals as to why the two statements with addClass() needed? And not one?

Comment: The comments in the code blocks will give you enough details. The first one is for complete URLs and the second one is for relative URLs

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's simple and clean. I thought I have to work with cookie!

Comment: Not sure where I'd add this?

Comment: After you've loaded the jquery library.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
You wrap the code in the answer around a <script> //javascript </script> tag.

Comment: @DannyG did u get how to set active in the parent for dropdown? can u help me?

Comment: This works perfectly with MVC. But you also 
if (window.location.search!='') {url += window.location.search;} for  parameters and add
.... .addClass('active').closest('.has-treeview').addClass('menu-open'); for opening menu trees.

Answer (score 30):

You don't really need any JavaScript with Bootstrap:

```
 <ul class="nav">
     <li><a data-target="#" data-toggle="pill" href="#accounts">Accounts</a></li>
     <li><a data-target="#" data-toggle="pill" href="#users">Users</a></li>
 </ul>
```

To do more tasks after the menu item is selected you need JS as explained by other posts here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Comment: this is the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

if you put

```
data-toggle="pill"
```

in the  tag it should work automatically.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

read under Markup

Comment: Amazing.  After all the non-working js crap.  Went through 3 questions with multiple answers to find out Bootstrap does have the built in toggle.

Comment: Works great!
Just add this code inside the <a> tag! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This did the job for me including active main dropdowns **and the active childrens** (thanks to 422):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    // Will only work if string in href matches with location
    $('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

    // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using an MVC framework with routes and actions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

As illustrated in this answer by Christian Landgren:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375529/101662

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
// Remove active for all items.
$('.page-sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');

// highlight submenu item
$('li a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Highlight parent menu item.
$('ul a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Best! Worked on AdminLTE

Comment: Must be ran after menu has been rendered.  For AdminLTE, it can be in _Layout before </Body> tag in some script tags.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me. It marks both simple nav elements and dropdown nav elements as active.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var url = window.location;

   $('ul.nav a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

   $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
      return this.href == url;
   }).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Passing `this.location.pathname` to  `$('ul.nav a[href="'...'"]')` marks also simple nav elements. Passing `url` did'nt work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are using Boostrap in Angulajs: this is a simple directive that works for me (because data-toggle cited by Kam is not included in Angular-ui). Hope can help.

```
app.directive("myDataToggle", function(){
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var e = angular.element(element);
        e.on('click', function(){
            e.parent().parent().children().removeClass('active');
            e.parent().addClass("active");
        })
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
});
```

---

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a href="#/page1" my-data-toggle>Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page2" my-data-toggle>Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page3" my-data-toggle>Page3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple and there is no need for server side or ajax, you only need jQuery and Bootstrap. On every page add an `id` to the `body` tag. Use that `id` to find a tag that contains the page name (value of a tag).

Example:

**page1.html**

```
<body id="page1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**page2.html**

```
<body id="page2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#page1 a:contains('Page1')").parent().addClass('active');
        $("#page2 a:contains('Page2')").parent().addClass('active');
     });
</script>
```

Big thanks to Ben! [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx0IysyYLH0)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and this is what I added in my app launch script, and it worked smoothly. Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  var navs = $('nav > ul.nav');

  // Add class .active to current link
  navs.find('a').each(function(){

    var cUrl = String(window.location).split('?')[0];
    if (cUrl.substr(cUrl.length - 1) === '#') {
      cUrl = cUrl.slice(0,-1);
    }

    if ($($(this))[0].href===cUrl) {
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $(this).parents('ul').add(this).each(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And the corresponding HTML is shown below. I'm using [CoreUI](http://coreui.io/), a phenomenal open source admin template and has support for many front end frameworks like Angular, plain bootstrap, Angular 4 etc.

```
<div class="sidebar">
<nav class="sidebar-nav open" >
    <ul class="nav" id="navTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"    href="/summary"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashboard </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"    href="/balanceSheet"><i class="icon-chart"></i> Balance Sheet </a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-title border-bottom">
            <p class="h5 mb-0">
                <i class="icon-graph"></i> Assets
            </p>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a hitch with the accepted answer in some rare cases for bootstrap 4:
In order to use the solution for relative paths like:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-t">
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.php" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.php" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.php" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="info.php" class="nav-link">Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you will find out that the code for:

```
 if (activePage == currentPage) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    }
```

active page returns the whole url and current location returns the current href DOM Element value which is filename.php.
To solve this just tweak the code a little by adding a method to correct this:

```
//... other js/jquery code
var activeMenuItemChanges=function () {
    function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
        if(str.substr(-1)=='/'){
            return str.substr(0, str.length -1);
        }
        return str;
    }
    // for cases where we do not use full url but relative file names in the href of ul>li>a tags:
    function getRelativeFileName(str){
        let page=str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        if(page.length > 0){
            return page;
        }
        return 'index'|'index.php';
    }

    let url=window.location.pathname;

    let activeLocation=stripTrailingSlash(url);

    let activeFileName=getRelativeFileName(activeLocation);

    $('.nav-item a').each(function() {
        let currentLocation=stripTrailingSlash($(this).attr('href'));
        if(activeFileName==currentLocation){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
activeMenuItemChanges();

//... other js/jquery code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete Twitter bootstrap example and applied active class based on query string.

Few steps to follow to achieve correct solution:

1) Include latest jquery.js and bootstrap.js javascript file.

2) Include latest bootstrap.css file

3) Include querystring-0.9.0.js for getting query string variable value in js.

4) HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#?page=0">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#?page=1">
            Forums
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#?page=2">
            Blog
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#?page=3">
            FAQ's
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#?page=4">
            Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#?page=5">
            Create
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery in Script Tag:

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
        $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var page = $.QueryString("page");
            $(".nav li:eq(" + page + ")").addClass("active");
        }, 300);

    });
});
```

I have done complete bin, so please click here http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpaf

Comment: Looks interesting, but not keen on the url structure one bit. Thanks though for your effort. Nice but not what I am after, cheers anyway

Comment: As per your given issue detail, i have done same thing so can you please explain in detail what you want in url structure..?

Comment: Why would I want to rename the url's to #?page=1 etc

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. My Bootstrap setup navigates to separate pages (so I can't do it on a click action, but the active class is removed on the navigation to a new page), and my urls don't match exactly. So here's what I did, based on my exception-based situation. Hope it helps others:

```
//Adding the active class to Twitter bootstrap navs, with a few alternate approaches

$(document).ready(function() {
  var rawhref = window.location.href; //raw current url 
  var newpage = ((window.location.href.match(/([^\/]*)\/?$/)[1]).substring(1)); //take only the last part of the url, and chop off the first char (substring), since the contains method below is case-sensitive. Don't need to do this if they match exactly.
  if (newpage == 'someNonMatchingURL') {  //deal with an exception literally
    newpage = 'matchingNavbarText'
    }
  if (rawhref.indexOf('somePartofURL') != -1) { //look for a consistent part of the path in the raw url to deal with variable urls, etc.
    newpage = "moreMatchingNavbarText"
    }
  $(".nav li a:contains('" + newpage + "')").parent().addClass('active'); //add the active class. Note that the contains method requires the goofy quote syntax to insert a variable.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To activate the menus and submenus, even with params in the URL, use the code bellow:

```
// Highlight the active menu
$(document).ready(function () {
    var action = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    // If there's no action, highlight the first menu item
    if (action == "") {
        $('ul.nav li:first').addClass('active');
    } else {
        // Highlight current menu
        $('ul.nav a[href="/' + action + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

        // Highlight parent menu item
        $('ul.nav a[href="/' + action + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

This accepts URLs like:

> /posts
>   /posts/1
>   /posts/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
// Highlight the active nav link.
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$('.navbar a[href$="' + filename + '"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

});

For more details [Click Here!](https://gist.github.com/mattnorris/5114074)