# current page menu 's background color doesn't change

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fht7zsm2/

I used below code to change background color for current page

```
.sf-menu .active{
             background-color:#1B3E70;
             color:white;

        }
```

I placed below script in footer.I also tried placing in header but doesn't work:

```
<script>
$('.sf-menu a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
</script>
```

I refered to this :
[Change link color of the current page with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/how-to-change-the-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css)

AND 
http://jsfiddle.net/7VBy9/

Answer (score 0):

In your case both `<a>` are not siblings as it is inside different `<li>` which are siblings

```
$('.sf-menu a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/fht7zsm2/3/)

Comment: @anpsmn.I tried but the links become unclickable.Why?

Comment: I had given return false as your href was blank

Comment: @samantha If the link points to another page and if you want to make the class active you will have to do that at the server side

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the  tags in de JavaScript part of JSFiddle. They're not needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/fht7zsm2/

```
$('.sf-menu a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

other `<a>` are not the sibling of `<a>`

or you can also use this

```
$('.sf-menu a').click(function () {
    $('.sf-menu a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fht7zsm2/2/

Comment: the color changes for selected menu tab ,but it's not directing to the page.WOnder why

Comment: because of `e.preventDefault()` you want both page to redirect and add background color

Comment: can u explain to me what I should do..my knowledge in javascript very poor

Comment: static website ? then add class in html for the menu you want on every page if

Comment: No..it's dynamic...but the links are provided in the menu but still why doesn't link?

Comment: like this:<ul class="sf-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/">
                    <img src='<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_1.png"; ?>' onmouseover='this.src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_2.png"; ?>"' onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_1.png"; ?>'"></a>
 </li>

Comment: try removing prevent default `$('.sf-menu a').click(function () {
        $('.sf-menu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    });`

Comment: I did...guess what the background color gone.and only appears when i click and I understand why..but solution i dont know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li this can help you