# Rails Bootstrap Active class with ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap active class to my navigation links but currently it's not working with my ordering in rails. The class is supposed to be applied when the clicked link matches the current URL.

This is the URL when the ordering is set

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?order=hot
```

But it's not actually applying the active class, as I'm guessing it's the '?' that's breaking it.

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('.sorting ul li a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

This code doesn't seem to be working with the '?'. From this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li)

Comment: When you click the link, does it reload the whole page, or is this done dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're reloading the whole page (as mentioned in the comment), you could skip the Javascript altogether, and do something in the view like (HAML example, let me know if you need an ERB example);

```
%li
  %a{href: '#', class: "#{'active' if params[:order] == 'hot'}"} 
    Link text here
```

This will read the GET parameter (`?order=`) from the URL, then add the `active` class to this `a` tag, if it is set as `hot`.

The Javascript example in the Bootstrap docs is how you would do it if you were dynamically updating the content.

**Edit**: and here's the untested ERB version;

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="<%= if params[:order] == 'hot' %>active<% end %>">
    Link text here
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: ERB would be brilliant - you knew it would happen! ;)

Comment: Have added an example! Let me know how you get on!

Comment: <%= link_to posts_path(order: :hot), class: "<%= if params[:order] == 'hot' %>active<% end %>" do %>
            Popular
          <% end %>

Comment: That is throwing a huge error in my face. 'index.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting keyword_end <li> ^ '

Comment: Don't use `<%= %>` inside another, use `"#{ }"` instead. `<%= %>` identifies whats inside it as Ruby, so, put simply, it won't nest!