# Bootstrap button not active on page navigation (Drupal 7)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a bootstrap button group with few buttons each of them with their a tag that links to a new page. I've added the jquery code for retaining the active state when a button is clicked. The buttons stay active on clicking only if there is no #href. When there is a link and the new page is loaded, the active state is lost. Can someone please help ? I am so lost!

Here is the snippet -
html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-custom">Home </a> 
    <a class="btn btn-custom" href="/link1"> About us </a>
    <a class="btn btn-custom" href="/link2"> Contact us </a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I've also changed these buttons to nav tabs and used this solution for persistent tabs http://aidanlister.com/2014/03/persisting-the-tab-state-in-bootstrap/ but to no avail. Same problem. Active state is lost when the new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is possible to maintain the active state on a new page load.

However, a simple workaround is to apply styling via bootstrap on each page so that the appropriate button appears active. For example if you were on the page link1:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-custom">Home </a> 
    <a class="btn btn-custom active" href="/link1"> About us </a>
    <a class="btn btn-custom" href="/link2"> Contact us </a>
</div>
```

This would make the button appear to be active.

Comment: Thanks but this makes all buttons active on start. I want them to be active only when they are clicked and the page is loaded.

Comment: So if I were on the "Home" page you do not want any buttons active. But if I were to click on "link1" you would want the button for link1 to be active when the page loaded correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. When I am on link1, page loads, link1 button is active and rest are not active.

Comment: So to do that you need to go to link1.html page and then paste the code block from my answer into the html page. This should provide the functionality you want. Keep your Home page the same.

Comment: Sorry but I am on drupal 7 with a bootstrap button block that spans across all pages. Thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me if someone is also looking for a solution. Changed buttons to Nav and lists.

```
  var url = window.location;
    // Will only work if string in href matches with location
    $('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
```

From [Twitter Bootstrap add active class to li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li)