# add class to parent li when submenu selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i know this question is been so much in this forum, but i am having a problem here despite googling for hours. I want when i selected /click submenu the parent `li` get class `.actives` using Javascript/Jquery. Thanks for your help :)
Here is my code:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid container">
        <div class="row m04m">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav">
                    <span class="bars">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="btn-text">Select Page</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index-2.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=" dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="about-us.html">About Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about-plasma.html">About Jump</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">LINK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> <!--Main Nav-->
```

and here is my css

```
.actives{background-color:#174069;}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: where is your javascript

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example code will help you modify it as your requirement

```
$('#menu').find('li').click(function(){
       //removing the previous selected menu state
       $('#menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');

        //is this element from the second level menu?
        if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('secondLevel')){
             $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

        //this is a parent element
        }else{
             $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });


#menu li.active{
    background: #ccddff;
}
```

demo sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/L94N6/4/