# Bootstrap navigation slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a navigation slider. To be more precice there is the standard navbar - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/# and three items: Home, About and Contact. The home item is set to active.
How to create the slider beneath of the active item?

[image]

And then when I click About, the white line should move to new active element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there isn't a backend to do this for you, you'll need some javascript to manipulate the nav and update to whichever is active:

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301507/bootstrap-css-active-navigation). Please search before asking next time.