# Add active class dynamically to bootstrap menu and opening its page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is a code of `HTML` that I created for navigation bar using `bootstrap`.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I need to add this `li`'s `active` class dynamically for menu items when that page is open.

I just check these two stackoverflow question : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301507/bootstrap-css-active-navigation) | [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533542/twitter-bootstrap-add-active-class-to-li)

But I couldn't figure this out.

This is my javascript -

```
$('#menu > ul.navbar-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope someone will help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: you have a problem in `$('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');` it should be `$('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');`

Comment: also there is no need for the `if` since you are removing the `active` class in the click handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tj38Lv63/1/

Comment: Now active class is adding to menu items. but its corresponding page is not loading...

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using Bootstrap, include the defult javascript plugins **bootstrap.js** or the minified **bootstrap.min.js** you can have menus items dynamically actived by adding **data-toggle="tab"** to your li elements like this

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">videos</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">Comment</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As written in the official document, check [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

> You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab" or data-toggle="pill" on an element. Adding the nav and nav-tabs classes to the tab ul will apply the Bootstrap tab styling, while adding the nav and nav-pills classes will apply pill styling.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/44/)):

```
$('#menu > ul.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Btw, you should target the `<a>` instead of `li`. You may need to retrieve the `href` value and `$(this).attr('href')` will return it but you can do it either way, anyways.

Also, this will only handle highlighting the `active` item but you need to add code to load the clicked page and hope you'll do it using `ajax` and you know how to do it.

### Update:

If you want to load the clicked item/page normally (without using `JavaScript/ajax`) then you need to remove `e.preventDefault()` but in this case this code won't highlight the active `li` and you need to do it from server side and other 3 answers are also given according to your current question which is about highlighting the current clicked item, you didn't mention anything about page loading and I assumed you are doing it using `ajax` and so did others as well (I think so).

### Update for Ajax:

```
$('#menu > ul.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();

    // Load the page content in to element
    // with id #content using ajax (There are other ways)
    $('#content').load($this.href());
});
```

Read more about it on [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: This is not about opening the page, you didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: why its stopping the page loading after adding this code?

Comment: You didn't write any (`ajax`) code to load the page and `e.preventDefault()` is stopping from loading the page normally but if you remove this then the active item won't be highlighted using this code.

Comment: Yes I can do it from server side. But here I am looking for a solution using jquery. Can you show me an example how to use `ajax` for this?

Comment: In this method, doesn't load full page only a part is loading to #content. isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right and you should do it on the server side, all the best :-)

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple and no need from server side or ajax, you only need jQuery and Bootstrap. On every page add ID to -body- tag . Use that ID to find -a- tag that contains page name(value of -a- tag).

Example:

**page1.html**

```
<body id="page1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
 <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**page2.html**

```
<body id="page2">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
 <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
    $(function () {
        $("#page1 a:contains('Page1')").parent().addClass('active');
        $("#page2 a:contains('Page2')").parent().addClass('active');
     });
```

Big thanks to Ben! [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx0IysyYLH0)

Comment: If you're going to go this route, you can opt for a pure CSS solution instead of relying on JS. Add the IDs and HREF class to your declarations. This will work as long as your page IDs and unique nav link classes are static.

Answer (score 2):

I think this line will fix the problem

You are saying

```
$('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
```

But there is no element which has the class `.navbar` you should just say `.nav`.

```
$('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/40/)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I came across the same problem. I wanted to dynamically add the `active` class, the `aria-current` tag, and change the `title` of the page, whenever I would click on a different page. 
Below is my html navbar:

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="flyers.php">Flyers</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="promotions.php">Promotions</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="grocery.php">Grocery</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

The `jquery` iterates through all the `<a>` tags using the `.each()` function (`a[href*=".php"]` selects all `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute that contains a `.php` ). Then, it checks if the page's url `includes` the specific `href` of the current page (using `window.location`), which shows that it's been clicked. If it does, then it removes the `active` class and the `aria-current` attribute from all the links, and then adds it to the current page. It also takes the text of the title, and adds that to the `title` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav a[href*=".php"]').each(function() {
        if (String(location).includes($(this).attr('href'))) {
            $('a.nav-link.active').removeAttr('aria-current');
            $('a.nav-link.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).attr('aria-current', 'page');
            document.title = $(this).text().trim();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the style of the class altogether?

Easily done with javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname').style.property.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');                
        });            
    });
```

## [DEMO Bootstrap Navbar](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/6phjjras/)

I have used:

```
$('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
```

Instead of:

```
$('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
```

Add these line to onen page:

```
var test = $(this).find("a");
test.trigger('click');
```

### Update

This one is also working: `window.location.href=$(this).find("a").attr('href');`

```
setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href=$(this).find("a").attr('href');
},1000);//redirection after interval
```

Comment: this adding the class but not opening its page

Comment: This may load the page but won't highlight the active item because the page will be refreshed and clicked item can't be tracked then.

Comment: Ya sure @WereWolf-TheAlpha but OP should use backend code for setting active link. and `ajax` is also a option. Let it decide to OP.

Comment: can you show me an ajax example, I did never use ajax for this.

Comment: The demo code is extremely slow if you select a navbar element.  I almost downvoted for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li a').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

No need to wrap the nav with any id.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this as I found the tab index didn't actually change the link to another file but just applied the css.

The code:

```
$('#home a:contains("Home")').parent().addClass("active");
```

Didn't work at all in my environment, bit of head scratching later and devised this.

Solution:
Get the pathname and split it by "/" 
sample url: https://example.com/microsite/map.html
will result in a list like this (based on sample url and setup i.e a microsite on the server with its own html files):
,microsite, map.html with a length of 3
get the items and switch the values:

```
    $(function(){
      let pathParts = window.location.pathname.split(/);
      let yourLink = pathParts[2] // in this example
      switch(yourLink){
         case: 'index.html':
         $('a:contains("Home")').parent().addClass("active");
         break;
         case: 'about.html':
         $('a:contains("About")').parent().addClass("active");   
         break;
         default:
         $('a:contains("Home")').parent().addClass("active"); 
         // if yourLink is empty then default to the home page
         }
     });
```